# Java streams expression parse string to a double[m][n] (with n varying size)

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-stream

As part of parsing a configuration string I would like to convert a string into a double[][] array. The configuration string contains one or more (*m*) sets of three or more (*n*) elements.

For the input: *"0,0,0  | 500,0,10  |  0,300,20  | 500,300,30"*,
I would expect an output: *double[][]{{0,0,0},{500,0,10},{0,300,20},{500,300,30}}*

The listing below works, **however**, I would like to improve the code as follows (*and I am having a hard time achieving that*):

1. Make the code generic, for a variable number of n-elements, such that it would accept an input such as "0,0,0 | 500,0,10 | 0,300,20,***999*** | 500,300,30", where the output[2] = [0,300,20,999]. I currently use (`map(x -> new double[]{Double.parseDouble(x[0]),Double.parseDouble(x[1]),Double.parseDouble(x[2])})`) which I want to rewrite generically.
2. Ideally combine the two stream expressions into one expression, taking in the string and outputting the double[m][n] **in one go**. Is this possible?

Listing:

```
    String ss = "0,0,0  | 500,0,10  |  0,300,20  | 500,300,30";
    System.out.println(ss);
    
    String[][] result_s = 
            Arrays.
            stream(ss.split("\\|")).
            map(x -> x.trim().split(",")).
            toArray(size -> new String[size][1]);
    double[][] result_d = 
            Arrays.stream(result_s).
            //This next line is the embarrassing part and I would like to make it generic (so independent of number of elements
            map(x -> new double[]{Double.parseDouble(x[0]),Double.parseDouble(x[1]),Double.parseDouble(x[2])})
            .toArray(size -> new double[size][1]);
    
    double[][] result_new = Arrays.stream(ss.split("\\|")).collect(Collectors.toList(entry -> entry.x.trim().split(",")));
            Arrays.
            stream(ss.split("\\|")).
            map(x -> x.trim().split(",")).
            map(x -> new double[]{Double.parseDouble(x[0]),Double.parseDouble(x[1]),Double.parseDouble(x[2])}).
            toArray(size -> new String[size][1]);
    
    //Strings array
    System.out.println("String arrays");
    for(String[] rs : result_s) System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rs));
    
    //double array
    System.out.println("Double arrays");
    for(double[] rs : result_d) System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rs));
```

Output :

> 0,0,0  | 500,0,10  |  0,300,20  | 500,300,30
> String arrays
> [0, 0, 0]
> [500, 0, 10]
> [0, 300, 20]
> [500, 300, 30]
> Double arrays
> [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
> [500.0, 0.0, 10.0]
> [0.0, 300.0, 20.0]
> [500.0, 300.0, 30.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for the "embarrassing line", you can stream each `x`, which is a `double[]`, and `mapToDouble`:

```
.map(x -> Arrays.stream(x).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray())
```

Second, the two streams can be joined very simply. Without `toArray(size -> new String[size][1])`, the first stream is `Stream<String[]>`, which is also what `Arrays.stream(result_s)` produces.

`toArray` converts the stream to an array, while `Arrays.stream` converts an array to a stream, so `Arrays.stream(result_s)` is kind of *undoing* what `toArray(size -> new String[size][1])` did. The two lines can cancel each other out.

```
double[][] result_d =
        Arrays.stream(ss.split("\\|"))
                .map(x -> x.trim().split(","))
                .map(x -> Arrays.stream(x).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray())
                .toArray(double[][]::new);
```

Comment: There is no sense in specifying the dimension `[1]`. This causes an allocation of a single element `double[]` array for each stream element, just to get replaced by the stream element afterwards. You should specify an uninitialized array, i.e. `.toArray(size -> new double[size][]);` Or use the simpler `.toArray(double[][]::new);`